# BlackBerry Webworks Unknow Host domainname​.com :80 Error

Tags: jquery, html, blackberry-webworks

I am working on this app that loads all the everything from a server.

This are the sample of my config.xml

```
<content src="http://somedomain.com/test_dl/integrateLayout/inde​x.html" />
<access uri="http://somedomain.com/" subdomains="true">
<feature id="blackberry.ui.menu" />
<feature id="blackberry.ui.dialog" />
<feature id="blackberry.system" />
<feature id="blackberry.system.event" />
<feature id="blackberry.app" />
<feature id="blackberry.app.event" />
<feature id="blackberry.push" />
</access>
<rim:connection timeout="60000">
<id>TCP_WIFI</id>
<id>MDS</id>
<id>BIS-B</id>
<id>TCP_CELLULAR</id>
<id>WAP2</id>
<id>WAP</id> 
</rim:connection>
```

It was working fine yesterday but suddenly when I try to run the app. it gives me error Unknown host somedomain.com :80 error.

Currently I'm running the app on 9900 running on OS 7.1.

Can anyone please help?

Comment: is somedomain.com a placeholder word? Try loading the content url in your browser (on your blackberry) to see if it loads

Comment: somedomain.com is the name of the server which I'm pointing to. This is the actual name:<content src="http://dashberry.com/test_dl/integrateLayout/inde​x.html" />
<access uri="http://dashberry.com/" subdomains="true">. That's weird, it loads from the BB Browser but not from the app.

Comment: How big are the images you are trying to load?